# How to tell SQL Server to not include results that end with specific letters/numbers

Tags: sql-server

For an assignment I got, I have to create a request that list the flight numbers (`varchar`), the date of the flight and if there's a lay over (`varchar`, return `NULL` if not). However, the conditions to be put are that the date of the flight must be between September 1st 2005 and December 30th 2006 and the flight number must not end with 8 and/or 9.

I came with the following statement:

```
SELECT ID_VOL, DATE_DEP, ESCALE
FROM VOL
WHERE ID_VOL NOT LIKE ('%8','%9') 
  AND DATE_DEP BETWEEN '2005-09-01' AND '2006-12-30'
```

The query doesn't work. I've tried with only one of the `ID_VOL` condition and it works fine but it doesn't work when I put the second. It works if I put the same condition twice one for each number, but the assignment specify I can only do it with one condition/operator. So I'm kinda stuck on that one.

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` against a list. If you want to exclude values that end in `'8'` or `'9'`, why not use a pattern? For example `SomeCol LIKE '[ABC]'` would match the characters `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`.

Comment: well i said list, i meant by that that it displays the data, and they didn't show us patterns yet so i can only use simple conditions for now

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LIKE Expression is wrong.

```
SELECT ID_VOL,DATE_DEP,ESCALE
FROM VOL
WHERE ID_VOL NOT LIKE '%[89]' AND 
      DATE_DEP BETWEEN '20050901' AND '20061230';
```

Comment: My assignment specify i can only use one comparison operator for the flight numbers, so only one NOT LIKE for both

Comment: @Alexd'Astous, I wrote it the long way and edited already.

Comment: So, per the comments here and on the question, you can only have one `LIKE` expression but can't use a pattern? You'll going to have difficulty then, @Alexd'Astous . You need to either use 2 `LIKE` expressions or a pattern here.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I didn't noticed your edit, will try that bit and come back to you

Comment: @Larnu Cetin's code worked though, so it is possible with only one `LIKE` expression or without pattern

Comment: `[89]` is a pattern, @Alexd'Astous .

Comment: @Larnu, probably assignment didn't say that he can't use a pattern. Otherwise, I too wonder how that would be.

Comment: @Larnu really? Well now I feel dumb, my teacher used another word to describe that, but i guess i mistranslated it (french is my first language so sorry for the confusion)

Comment: No worries; this explains the confusion when you said you couldn't use a pattern, but also were limited to a single `LIKE`, @Alexd'Astous , as the statements effectively conflicted.